# Can I force the tkinter.Text widget to wrap lines on the "space" character as well as words?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, word-wrap

Below is an example tkinter app with a `Text` field which wraps to the next line on long words, as expected. The issue, however, is that *spaces* don't wrap to the next line in the same way. I am able to enter as many spaces as I like prior to the start of a new word and a line wrap won't occur. Once I begin typing any other printable characters (as well as tabs and newlines), the text wraps as expected.

How can I configure my `Text` widget to *also* wrap on whitespace at the end of the line? Is there a better method than, say, parsing out the length of the line in question (with `Text.count()`, perhaps) and forcing a newline after `width` characters?

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, wrap='word', width=40, height=10)
text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @toyotaSupra the `WORD` constant evaluates to the string literal `'word'`, which I'm already using. Besides which, that's not the issue I'm having.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Again, this is not the issue. 1. It's not strictly necessary to set window geometry, so I've skipped it here for the sake of brevity. My application *does* explicitly set window geometry and this makes no difference. 2. `root` (i.e., `tk.Tk`) has no `wraplength` option, and for that matter, neither does the `Text` widget - this raises a `TclError`

Comment: @toyotaSupra: the root window doesn't support a `wraplength` attribute.

Comment: @toyotaSupra The `Text` widget *does not* support `wraplength`, as I have already said. `Text` only has the `wrap` parameter, and the valid arguments are: `'word'` (which I'm using),  `'char'` (the default), and `'none'`. And none of those have anything to do with the root window.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Now you're just messing with me...what on Earth would this accomplish?

Comment: Very sorry. That all I can help.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Respectfully, you haven't helped yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap spaces in a `tag` with `wrap` option set to "char".

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

class Text(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<KeyPress-space>', self.char_space)
        self.tag_configure('space', wrap='char')
    
    def char_space(self, event=None) -> str:
        self.insert('insert', ' ', 'space')
        return 'break'

       
text = Text(root, wrap='word', width=40, height=10)
text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I did have to change `text.insert` to `self.insert`, but other than that this is perfect. Thanks for the help

Comment: @`text.insert`  it isn't like me to make a mistake like that. I wonder how that got there. It's not in my scratch.py that I use to test my answers. hmm. I have no clue where that came from. Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: it happens - no harm done!